# How can I host my javascript web application on Github Pages?

Tags: javascript, html, css, github, github-pages

Recently I started building a small single page application for reducing anxiety. I am trying to host this basic CSS/HTML/Javascript website on GH pages but can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong after hours of looking on the web.

The project: https://github.com/GrovesJames/Release

Any tips or guidance would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: You need to enable github pages for the repository in the repository settings.

Comment: I try that but I get this error when I visit the site: "404 file not found. The site configured at this address does not contain the requested file. If this is your site, make sure that the filename case matches the URL. For root URLs (like example.com) you must provide an index.html file. Read the full documentation for more information about using GitHub Pages."

Comment: Need to be more clear about what your question is, Read guidelines https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Trisk set it to `master branch /docs folder ` and wait. It usually takes upwards of 10 minutes for the CDN to catch up. Also make sure you are clearing your cache before reloading the page.

Comment: @Olian04 Gotcha. Now when I click it, it boots up a blank page. When I inspect it gives me this console error: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()"

Comment: @Olian04 after clearing my cache, the error now says "GET https://grovesjames.github.io/Release/main.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404"

Comment: @Trisk which is exactly what it should say. In your index.html file you are importing a javascript file that doesn't exist.

Comment: @olian04 the javascript file I am importing is in the src folder in the docs folder. should i just move all files related to the website to the main folder with the index.html?

Comment: @Olian04 oh I'm sorry, the src folder is in the main release folder. which is probably why the index cant find it. Where should I move my src folder / javascript files?

Answer (score 2):

In Your web application repository click on settings, then scroll down until you find **GitHub Pages**:

[image]

Then click on `none` and change it to `master branch /docs folder`

Comment: I try that but I get this error when I visit the site: "404 file not found. The site configured at this address does not contain the requested file.

If this is your site, make sure that the filename case matches the URL.
For root URLs (like http://example.com/) you must provide an index.html file.

Read the full documentation for more information about using GitHub Pages."

Comment: What source did you select on GitHub pages? `master branch` **OR** `master branch /docs folder`?

Comment: I tried both sources and was given the same error for both :/

Comment: Try to move your `index.html` to `release` folder (the main folder)

Comment: I emptied my cache and it booted up my project but the error now says "after clearing my cache, the error now says "GET grovesjames.github.io/Release/main.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404"

Comment: @Trisk I have downloaded your code, and **fixed some errors and typos** , so here is what you have to change: **->**

in your `index.html` file replace `<script src="main.js"></script>` with `<script type="module" src="../src/index.js"></script>`

**and** in your `src/main.js` replace the first 3 lines with `import Home from './components/home.js'
import Write from './components/write.js'
import Done from './components/done.js'`

Comment: I did as you said, fixing the errors. It now gives me the error "GET http://localhost:8080/src/index.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: @Trisk Is there a way to show me what you've changed? take some screenshots or push the code you've changed to GitHub repo.

Comment: @Trisk I've took a look at what you've changed, and it's working just fine on my device: [screenshot-1](https://imgur.com/2ZrHbJX) [screenshot-2](https://imgur.com/AAlRbmP) [screenshot-3](https://imgur.com/jzrUw8p)

Comment: I pushed the changes up to the master branch and is what is currently deployed. Could it be the browser I'm using? I can't seem to get it to work